# MakerBot Camera Stream

Tags: makerbot, services

Is it possible to use the onboard camera on the 5th+ generation MakerBot printers to stream or save to a file?

I'd like to try and use the stream for customers on my 3DHubs account and they recommend setting up a YouTube stream. However, even if I'm able to stream to VLC Player or something, I'd like to get the video/images somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I own the gen 5, not the gen 5+. As far as I can tell, the camera has not gotten much of an upgrade and the software is also just as limited. That said to be sure I verified on several sites such as this [reddit](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/makerbot/comments/2pop5m/will_the_makerbot_5th_gen_ever_be_able_to_stream/?client=safari).

There are some that claim that the software is open source. I do not think this is true given the parent company. Following even if it was you do not want to use their camera. It is shocking how cheap they went on this ultra premium printer. Which despite printing very well has not been received well. The main issue is that the camera is 320 by 240! That alone is enough to derail your quest I am afraid.

Take a look at this [raspberry pi project](http://metatek.blogspot.com/2014/02/raspberry-pi-makerbot-cam.html) on building your own camera set up. Though really any wireless camera setup should do. Using a Pi has the stand alone advantage.

Comment: I agree, the camera is not that great, but I'd rather utilize the camera as much as I can. It's been good enough to double check the status and have my wife get it back up and running if it's stopped. I've tried right clicking the video feed in MakerBot Print and long pressing in the Android App, but there aren't any options that pop-up to save anything.

Comment: The only hope then might be https://www.makerbot.com/media-center/2014/06/19/makerbot-developer-program-invitation-innovate

Comment: 320 by 240? I think the sensor in my mouse has better res than that... what happened, did they find a crate of old camera phones from 2003?

Comment: @tbm0115 I think the answer is a resounding no. The system has bumped up the question so it can get marked off.